# Argue with Taylor's formula with remainder that this holds.

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, analysis, taylor-expansion

I get Taylorpolynomials and that the remainder is of course the difference of the function and its taylorpolynomial to the n'th degree. But the rest is kind of throwing me off and how to use the fact that we know the derivative of n'th degree and that this is true for x bigger than 1.

[image]

Comment: Separate to the question, you should be aware that 'Taylor polynomial' should be two words in English; the one-word version is perhaps based on a translation from German or another language where the term is a single word.

Answer (score 3):

Taylor's theorem says $f(x)-T_n(x)=\frac{f^{(n+1)}(\xi)}{(n+1)!}(x-1)^{n+1}$ for some $\xi$ between $1$ and $x$.  Taking absolute values,
$$
|f(x)-T_n(x)|=\left|\frac{f^{(n+1)}(\xi)}{(n+1)!}(x-1)^{n+1}\right|\leq M\,\frac{|x-1|^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}.
$$
where $M$ is any upper bound on $|f^{(n+1)}(x)|$.
Therefore, your strategy is to show
$$
\frac{|f^{(n+1)}(x)|}{(n+1)!}\leq\frac{1}{n+1},
$$
or equivalently,
$$
|f^{(n+1)}(x)|\leq n!
$$
Plugging in $f^{(n+1)}(x)=(-1)^n n! x^{-(n+1)}$, it should be clear.

Comment: Ah I see. So I end up actually just having to show a simple inequality and that x>1 for it to be true?

Comment: But wouldn't it be a < and not <= in the end? I mean it is always going to be smaller for x>1, right?

Comment: $<$ implies $\leq$. It's extremely common to use $\leq$ for this reason. But yeah, assuming $x>1$, it will be $<$.

Comment: and this would be in every step or do we actually need the last calculation to be certain?

Comment: Hmm I have 1 follow up question. Why does the function then behave strangely at x>2 if we look at what we have written so far? How can i extract that?

Comment: What you cite is Lagrange's form of the remainder. There are several others, which might be useful in different cases.

Comment: @vonbrand Oh so this is wrong using Taylors formula since it is Lagranges? ...

Comment: @vonbrand How would you in that case do it?

Comment: @zugzug I have taken a look at this for a whole now. This is true but it is using the Lagrange formula, though.